# Prevent "," and ";" on an email input field with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to prevent the use of "," and ";" on an input field with Jquery. I have been trying this solution so far:

HTML :

```
<input name="txt_correu-e" type="text" id="gestio_usuaris_editaCompta_txt_correu-e" size="50" maxlength="50" class="">
```

JQUERY:

```
$('#gestio_usuaris_editaCompta_txt_correu-e').keypress(function (e) {
    var filter = /([,;])/;
    var campo = $("#gestio_usuaris_editaCompta_txt_correu-e").val();
    if (filter.test(campo)) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
 });
```

But is not working for me since the input still print the character and then won't let me continue writting in the input. I just want the input to not show those characters but let me continue writting the email adress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent the user to type `,` and `;`, you can simply do :

```
$("#target").keypress(function( event ) {
    if ( event.which == 44 || event.which == 59 ) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }

    // other instructions

});
```

**Edit :**

To validate an email address, you can use :

```
function is_valid_email(email) {
    var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
    return regex.test(email);
}
```

which you can call in any needed event ( keyup, ... ) on your text field.

You can also use the [HTML5 email input](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.email.html) :

```
<form>
    E-mail: <input type="email" name="email">
</form>
```

Hope that can help.

Comment: thanks @akmozo that actually works, i was wondering how to make this work with a regular email validation using reg exps, checking the input in real time not just when i hit enter.

Comment: This doesn't allow you to put that key at all @Lowtrux. There's no enter here.

Comment: Keep in mind this solution will let the user copy and paste the "," and ";". If the user copies a list of emails from another source and paste it in your input, it will go through.
There's no need to use jQuery in here when you can use the `pattern` attribute to specify the correct RegEx in the input element.

Comment: Thanks @Charmander yeah the thing is i need this to work on IE8 and the pattern atribute won't work there.

Comment: @Lowtrux To be more secure you need also 1.to check the entire input.value for `;` and `,` presence and 2.to implement server side field validation

Comment: Can you post a solution that will fit your suggestion @morels ? Im kinda of a newbie with JQuery sorry.

Comment: @akmozo the OP needs to work with IE8, HTML5 email input is not compatible.

Comment: @Lowtrux posted some code in order to show you the first point.

Comment: @morels OP can use any method to validate the email, he is not forced to use the html5 email input when it's not supported !

Comment: @akmozo but why to suggest it if not supported? (in your edit you suggested also an `<input type="email">`)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#target").on('keyup click blur',function( event ) {
      var regex = new RegExp('^([A-Z0-9_.+-])+\@(([A-Z0-9-])+\.)+([A-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/', 'i');
      if(!regex.exec($(this).val())){
          $(this).val("");
          event.preventDefault();
    });
```

In order to avoid the insertion of unwanted characters you should listen to keyup event(keyboard), click event( to prevent right click and paste ;:-containing text) and blur event(if the input has been selected via TAB key in order to paste ;:-containing text).

For other mail-validation polices pls see [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html)

Answer (score 0):

Like I said in my comment, there's no need to use jQuery or JavaScript to do this, and restricting an input through the `keyPress` event is not a good practice, since anyone can copy and paste the content (not even with "evil" intentions).

The following solution would allow any characters except for "," and ";". Keep in mind this is not enough to ensure an email address is valid, of course.

```
<form>
    <input type="text" pattern="^[^,;]*$" required/>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/parvmck7/

Let me know if you have doubts.

**UPDATE:** I didn't realise you needed this to be compatible with IE8. If this is the case, you can try with any of the HTML5 Polyfills (https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills#web-forms). Otherwise, JavaScript will be.

Comment: Thanks @Charmander but i have to OP also in IE8 and this solution wont work for that Browser thats why i have to use JQuery

Comment: Sure, please update your question, because it's a key point in order to provide a adequate and useful answer.